# jquery - going to a page with anchor from an external page - issue with offset from a fixed top menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the script below to get smooth scrolling on an anchor and for returning to top of page (with also the back button of browser). This script works well when I am on the same page that anchors :

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {

  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    var hash = this.hash; // 'this' will not be in scope in callback
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55}, 300, function() {
      href = window.location.href;
      history.pushState({page:href}, null, href.split('#')[0]+hash);
    });
    return false;
  }
  }
  });

  $(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;
    var target = window.location.href.split('#');
    var href = target[0];
    if (state) {
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300, function() {
      history.replaceState({}, null, href);
      });
    }
  });
```

Now, I would like to go on the anchors of this page (page A) from another page (page B) or directly from pasting the URL of page A with an anchor.

For example, If I put directly on URL address bar of browser :

`http://domain.com/test.html#anchorName` , I am redirected to the section "`anchorName`" of the page `test.html`

The problem is a little more complex because I have a top fixed menu which appears when I start to scroll down the page. When I put directly the URL `http://domain.com/test.html#anchorName` into browser address bar, I want to be the `#anchorName` section of test.html but without being hidden by the top fixed menu.

So, I have added to the above script an offset of 55 (height of fixed top menu) by doing :

```
 if ($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
    var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
    if (target.length) {
      var hash = this.hash; // 'this' will not be in scope in callback
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55}, 300, function() {
      location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  }
```

But the issue is that if I go back to the top of page and click again on an anchor, I have a light shifting on the target, it looks like an offset was cumulated with the previous smooth scrolling (this behavior has been seen on Fifefox and Chrome)

For example, you can click on the following [test link to go directly on anchor](http://93.184.46.144/info/triple_pendulum_test#equations). Once you are on the section, return to the top of page by clicking on right bottom icon : then if you click on the same anchor link as the previous one (from the top menu), you will see there is a little shift, it seems that offset is cumulated with the previous one (55+55=110) whereas I still use `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55` .

Someone could see what's wrong with this light shift ?

Feel free to give comments if you have not understood all,

Thanks

**COMPLEMENTARY INFORMATIONS :**

Concerning the right bottom icon with which we can return to the top, I am using the following script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                          

    // hide #back-top first                                                             
    $("#back-top").hide();                                                              

    // fade in #back-top                                                                
    $(function () {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {                                                
        $('#back-top').fadeIn();                                                        
        } else {
        $('#back-top').fadeOut();                                                       
        }
        });                                                                             

      // scroll body to 0px on click
      $('#back-top a').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0                                           
        }, 300, function() {
          var target = window.location.href.split('#');                                 
          var href = target[0];
          history.replaceState({}, null, href);                                         
          });                                                                           
        });                                                                             
      });                                                                               
});
```

Comment: My first try would go for something like: animate to the correct position, make a callback function, scroll back X pixel?

Comment: If you are already adding 55px to offset the height on page load why not just adjust this number so it matches up with the positioning with what is currently working?